# How to populate textboxes-Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

What I am trying to do is basically populate textboxes with item names in one xaml (Basket) when selecting item from another xaml(Menu). My code is below :

**Menu.xaml**

In here when I click a button I want it to automaticallly appear in a textbox in the Basket.xaml.

```
    public class PassedData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
    private void Vanbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Basket), new PassedData { Name = "Cheese" });
    }

    private void LCbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Basket), new PassedData { Name = "Crisp" });
    }
```

**Basket.xaml**

```
       protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Menu.PassedData data = e.Parameter as Menu.PassedData;
    /**    ItemChosentxt.Text = data.Name;
        ItemChosentxt2.Text = data.Name;
        ItemChosentxt3.Text = data.Name;
        ItemChosentxt4.Text = data.Name;**/


    }
```

The commented out part adds the name of the item selected. instead of just adding to one textboxit adds to all of the textboxes. i.e. If i select the vanilla btn in Menu.xaml the Name appears in all 4 textboxes instead of just one. So I decided to implement code in each textboxes:

```
private void ItemChosentxt_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Menu.PassedData data = e.Parameter as Menu.PassedData;
        ItemChosentxt.Text = data.Name;
    }

    private void SecItem_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Menu.PassedData data = e.Parameter as Menu.PassedData;
        SecItem.Text = data.Name;
    }
```

This displays an error underneath the e.Parameter the error code is -

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
    Error   CS0103  The name 'data' does not exist in the current context
```

and

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'TextChangedEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Parameter' and no extension method 'Parameter' accepting a first argument of type 'TextChangedEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I am developing a shopping app so e.g. if user selects "Vanilla" and "Cake" from menu how can I make the name be displayed in the Basket textboxes? I am new to app development and apologise for the long question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you aren't supplying TextChangedEventArgs e with PassedData.

The compiler is specifically yelling at you

1. for saying e.Paramenter (TextChangedEventArgs doesn't have a "Parameter" member)
2. for using "data", which is undefined because of 1.

However, I recommend a completely different approach. Just use a listview (and data binding). 
 Example:

**Basket.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PassedData}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**Basket.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

    // namespace ...

public sealed partial class Basket : Page
{
    private static ObservableCollection<Menu.PassedData> passedData = new ObservableCollection<Menu.PassedData>();
    public ObservableCollection<Menu.PassedData> PassedData
    {
        get { return passedData; }
        set { passedData = value; }
    }


    /*Events*/

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /*Methods*/

    /// Fires PropertyChangedEventHandler, for bindables
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        var ev = PropertyChanged;
        if (ev != null)
        {
            ev(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public Basket()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        Menu.PassedData data = e.Parameter as Menu.PassedData;
        /**    ItemChosentxt.Text = data.Name;
            ItemChosentxt2.Text = data.Name;
            ItemChosentxt3.Text = data.Name;
            ItemChosentxt4.Text = data.Name;**/
        if (data != null)
        {
            PassedData.Add(data);
        }

    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Menu));
    }
}
```

}